# Aloha! VERY broad CPT questions. Looking for the theory/best practices behind it

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

Aloha,

I'm new to CPTs and fear that Iʻm making too many.

1. I have 8 Research Areas - Should they be a CPT?
2. Each Research Area will have 5 "types" of data - Should these be separate CPTs?

I think "News" could be better handled by stock WP Posts?

Should I be thinking of taxonomy (categories) instead of CPTs?

Any advice on how you might approach this would be sincerely appreciated.

Mahalo - Bill

[image: Structure - CPT]

Comment: Hello! Questions here need to be specific and answerable with facts, but this seems more like a discussion. You need to be able to mark an answer as not just what was most useful to you, but as the answer, the canonical answer that all people with this question would look at and say "yes, that is the answer". If it's a discussion of best practices or opinions you're wanting then this sites format doesn't work for that as this isn't a discussion forum

Comment: Thanks, Tom - I found the related discussion on this post very useful and was hoping for the same here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/351192/does-wordpress-support-an-unlimited-or-large-number-of-custom-post-types

Iʻll look elsewhere.

Comment: That one was more for how many different types of CPT is feasible, usually broad questions mean you need to ask multiple more specific questions as part of research, in this case it sounds like you need information about various subjects such as what are custom taxonomies